# Как реализовать сравнение n-ного столбца и n-ного ряда матрицы?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать код, в котором реализовано сравнение n-ных строк и n-ных столбцов матрицы между собой и вывод на экран количества одинаковых столбцов и строк? Сам я смог реализовать запись чисел в виде матрицы (код скину под сообщением). Мне нужно, чтобы кто-то помог доработать код согласно условиям, которые я привел выше.

Обещанный код:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
            int i, j, N, M, a[20][20];
            cout << "N="; 
            cin >> N;
            cout << "M="; 
            cin >> M;
            cout << "Input matrix A \n";
        
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                
                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                    cin >> a[i][j]; 
            cout << "matrix A \n";
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                
                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t"; 
                cout << endl; 
            }
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) if (a[n][i] == a[i][n]) { ... они равны ... }`

Comment: Прошу прощения а ви не могли би подсказать в каюю именно чясть моего кода я должен добавить ето условие чтоби он нормально работал?

Comment: После печати матрицы. Внутри цикла `for (n = 0; n < N; n++) { ... }` / Кстати, матрица д.б. квадратной, поэтому переменная `M` не нужна

Comment: можете вставить ето в код и прислать потомучьто я питаюсь у меня некоректно работает и если можете об'ясните пожалуйста как именно должна роботать программа если все коректно сложить .

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    int N, M, a[20][20];
    cout << "N=";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "M=";
    cin >> M;

    if (N != M) {
        cout << "Длины строк не равны длинам столбцов, одинаковых нет\n";
        return 0;
        }

    cout << "Input matrix A \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    cout << "matrix A \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";

        cout << endl;
        }

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        bool eql = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            if (a[i][j] != a[j][i]) {
                eql = false;
                break;
                }
            }

        if (eql) count++;
        }

    cout << count << " одинаковых столбцов и строк\n";
    }
```